# Scripting GUI buttons to trigger an event of changing materials

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Apologies if there's a similar question, however, I have probably seen it and it has not fixed my problem.

I am trying to write a JS script for unity in order to achieve an event to be triggered once clicked.

I have searched online on UnityAnswers website and others, the closest I can get is based on these questions 
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/368303/changing-shaders-of-a-gameobject-via-script-1.html

and this one
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/319875/change-objects-material-using-gui-buttons-via-scri.html

and also looked at this one 
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-shader.html

So, my code is this so far

```
var button2_tex : Texture;
var button3_tex : Texture;
var button4_tex : Texture;
var seat_mat1 : Material;
var seat_mat2 : Material;
var veneer1 : Texture;
var veneer2 : Texture;
var rend : Renderer;
var _mouseDown = false;



function Start() {

    seat_mat1 = Resources.Load( "seat_mat1" );
    seat_mat2 = Resources.Load( "seat_mat2" );

}

function Update(){

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){

            _mouseDown = true;

        }

}

function OnGUI() {

GUI.Box (Rect (10,10,100,200), "Menu");

        if (_mouseDown){

            if (GUI.Button (Rect (20,40,40,20), button1_tex)){

            if(seat_mat1){


                rend.material = seat_mat2;
                Debug.Log("This button was clicked!");
                }

            else{

                rend.material = seat_mat1;
                }

            }

        }
```

Please note some variables I haven't used yet, as am still testing bunch of other codes to get it working..

the code snippet I am trying to fix starts with "function OnGUI()" but I maybe wrong and could use some fresh insight.

this is a screenshot of the resulting script. The button on the left side is supposedly to change the colour of the material from seat_mat1 to seat_mat2 by the event of mouse clicking on the button.

[image]

I have attached the previous script to the 3D object in unity and had made a folder names "Resources" for the materials to be visible and referenced through the script.

My problem is that upon clicking the GUI button, nothing happens, and it maybe something very simple and I am just missing it .. apologies for being inexperienced in JS much or unity.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

So after playing a bit more with the code. I added a Debug.Log() after this line

```
GetComponent.<Renderer>().material = seat_mat2;
Debug.Log("This button was clicked!");
```

and seems to be this error that I am getting every time the button is pressed

> "MissingComponentException: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the "scene_export3" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
>       You probably need to add a Renderer to the game object "scene_export3". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
>       materialChanger.OnGUI () (at Assets/materialChanger.js:44)"

So with simple understanding, it seems that the renderer is not attached somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine But still i think once you have loaded The materials in start function you do not need to load them every time. And one thing more is to make sure you have applied the script to the gameobject you want to change the material of. If you just want to change the color not want to change complete material use color property of material and your OnGUI function should look like this.

```
function OnGUI() {

GUI.Box (Rect (10,10,100,200), "Menu");

    if (_mouseDown){

        if (GUI.Button (Rect (20,40,40,20), button1_tex)){

            if(GetComponent.<Renderer>().material == seat_mat1)


                GetComponent.<Renderer>().material.color = seat_mat2.color;


            else

                GetComponent.<Renderer>().material.color = seat_mat1.color;

            }

        }

    }
```

But if you do not use color poperty it will work fine just make sure you have applied script to game boject you want to change material i your case may be to your seat1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand that I don't need to load them each time, but i am still experimenting to achieve a working code. I know my could should theoretically work, however, there's something I cannot put my finger on that is not operating it. I attached the script to the gameObject as a whole, because I am looking to change the material of all the objects with the same material e.g. seat_mat1 to seat_mat2. Now I have understood that the renderer itself is not working to begin with as per my edit above, and now I am focusing on that and I hope to find an answer soon.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the issue because you have attached the script to wrong game object instead you should attach this script to the game object upon which a material is applied.

Comment: or you can apply seat_mat1 material to gameobject that has this script even then it will work . because the exception shows game object has no render but you are using  GetComponent.<Renderer>().material which will get the renderer of gameobject and if its not attached it will through exception

Comment: Yes, you were right, the script needed to be attached to gameObject rather than the whole group gameObject. However, even If I attached to all the needed gameObjects, the render changes the last object to get the script attached to ... but hey, at least it is working somehow :)

Comment: Acutely you can change material to the whole group with a little modification in your script. I am writing it for you wait for my next reply

Comment: You can do it in may ways but a simple way of doing this is to First make all the gameobjects in your group be the children of an empty game object.

Comment: Thank you, I will await your reply with your sample script :) Also I have edited my original script for a better working version. The minor referencing issue you mentioned earlier was fixed with this edited script

Comment: You can do it in may ways but a simple way of doing this is to First make all the gameobjects in your group be the children of an empty game object. replace your OnGUI function with this one

Comment: function OnGUI() {

GUI.Box (Rect (10,10,100,200), "Menu");

        if (_mouseDown){

            if (GUI.Button (Rect (20,40,40,20), button1_tex)){
    
    var rendArray : Renderer[];
    rendArray = GetComponentsInChildren(Renderer);
    
    for(var rendererItem : Renderer in rendArray)
    {
     
                 if(rendererItem.material == seat_mat1)
                     rendererItem.material.color = seat_mat2.color;
                 else
                     rendererItem.material.color = seat_mat1.color;
                }

            }

        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nain for your guidance, with your help I was able to come up with a partial solution, where I know I can fix from there. 
The solution is as follows.

The code:

```
function OnGUI() {

GUI.Box (Rect (10,10,100,200), "Menu");

        if (_mouseDown){

            if (GUI.Button (Rect (20,40,40,20), button1_tex)){


                var rendArray : Renderer[];

                rendArray = GetComponentsInChildren.<Renderer>(true); 

                for(var rend : Renderer in rendArray){

                if(rend.sharedMaterial == seat_mat1){

                    rend.sharedMaterial = seat_mat2;
                    Debug.Log("This button was clicked!");
                    }

                else{

                    rend.sharedMaterial = seat_mat1;
                    }

                   }

                }

            }

        }
```

After saving the script in MonoDevelop, open Unity where you create an empty game object and add all the objects with specific material e.g. seat_mat1 under it as children. 
Then click on the empty object, rename it if you like, and add a "Mesh Renderer" component from "Add Component > Mesh > Mesh Renderer".
After that drag the script to the empty object and in the inspector you can find an option which you can choose a renderer called "rend". Choose the empty object as the Mesh Renderer.

Upon testing the outcome, I have managed to change materials of some objects together to seat_mat2, but unrelated materials changed themselves to seat_mat1 and once the button is clicked again, they alternate between seat_mat1 and seat_mat2 
and even though it is not perfectly done, I am answering this question as anything else is fixable (I hope).

Thank you again Nain for your help :)